# Visual studio is syntax checking my C# as Visual Basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-checking

I've been testing some c# code in visual studio and when I opened visual studio this morning my project was full of red lines.

- Demanding class declarations to be closed with End class
- Red lines under semicolons
- Variable declaration without an AS clause
- Ctrl+K, CTRL+C Gives visual basic comments E.g. 'green text
- //C# comments get red squiggly lines under them.

These are clearly visual basic errors which means for some reason it's trying to make my C# into VB.

I've been trying to find out what on earth to search for but no luck so far.

When I build the project there is no problem. Just the syntax errors in visual studio with red squiggly lines.

Comment: If you create a new C# project (new instance of VS, new solution), does it do the same in that? Also, what version/edition of Visual Studio? Have you already e.g. attempted to run a repair on it?

Comment: It did not happen in a new project. Though I'm uncomfortable not knowing what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to :

- close VS
- delete .SUO file
- restart VS

> The SUO file is a hidden file,, which is placed in the same folder as
>   the SLN file. It contains a lot of information such as which files are
>   currently open in the IDE, some local settings, etc.

[More Information](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/quick-tip-what-to-do-when-visual-studio-freaks-out-and-everything-is-red/) about that.

Comment: Restarting helped but it did so before and then snapped back to the problem so I expect it might do so again. There is a small dropdown above the code to the upper left that says "Miscellaneous files" with a c# icon to it's left. When that is there the code is fine. After a while something happends and it changed to 1_filename.aspx.cs and then to 2_filename.aspx.cs and I have no idea what i did but the errors were back.

Comment: Miscellaneous files means VS doesn't recognize your file as a part of your project. So you can try to exclude this file in Solution Explorer, Right click on your projetc folder, Add,  Existing file and select your file.